# center of symmetry formula

Tags: functions, symmetry

How to prove that $I(0,-1)$ is the center of symmetry of the function 
$$F(x)= x - \dfrac{2e^x}{(e^x -1)}$$
Is there any formula that I can directly apply?

Answer (score 5):

A general rule simply involves shifting the function. Proving that $(a,b)$ is a center of symmetry for $f(x)$ is the same as proving that the function

$$f(x+a)-b$$

is symmetric around the origin. This means you have to prove
$$f(-x+a)-b=-(f(x+a)-b)$$

Comment: If $f(x)=-f(-x)\forall x \in R$, then $f(x)$ is a symmetric function about the origin. Shifting the origin to $(a,b)$ as you say, one would get: $f(x-a)-b=-(f(-(x-a))-b)$ which simplifies to $f(-x+a)-b=-f(x-a)+b$. But, it doesn't match with the RHS of your answer. Can you please take a look as to exactly why your method does not work in this case? Thanks!

Comment: @GaurangTandon Let $G(x) = f(x+a) - b$. Then $G(0) = 0$ and we want to $G(x)$ be an odd function. So $$G(-x) = -G(x) \implies f(-x+a) - b = -(f(x+a)-b)$$ which is the orion's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Define $y(x) = F(x) + 1$. As y is shifted $1$ upwards its center should be $(0,0)$.
Central symmetry in origin implies: $y(-x) = -y(x)$
You must demonstrate:

$F(-x) + 1 = -F(x) - 1$

Comment: Thanks but I want a more genral rule that I can use for any point

Comment: For any point (a,b): $$F(x-a)+b$$ should have central symmetry at origin. So: $$F(-x-a)+b=-F(x-a)-b$$. In other words: $$F(-x-a)+F(x-a)=-2b$$

Answer (score 1):

For any point $I(a,b)$, prove that 
$$f(a-x)+ f(x) =2b$$
In your case: $a=0$ and $b=-1$. 
Then you have to prove $f(-x)+f(x) =-2$